# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. IIS looks in a wrong path for web.config when trying to access static content

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I get the following error when the ASP.NET tries to retrieve picture at http://myapplication.com/Uploads/Help/picture.png address from the IIS:

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Config Error: Cannot read configuration file

Config File: \\?\D:\Inetpub\myapplication.com\Uploads\web.config
```

Why the IIS is looking for the web.config in the "Uploads" folder instead of the root folder?

Windows Server 2008 R2

Static Content installed

StaticFileModule present in the StaticFileHandler

Best regards

Comment: Is the `D:\Inetpub\myapplication.com\Uploads` is mapped to an application or a website?

Comment: Check the physical path in IIS>manage Website > Advanced Settings. Maybe this is pointing to your uploads folder?